# eloquent multi table query and relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am new to this so bear with me.

I have 4 tables (users, scores, scorecards, courses) and I need to bring into a view info from all of these tables.

Here are the relationships:

Scores model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function scorecard(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Scorecard');
}

public function course() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');
}
```

Course model

```
public function club(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Club');

}

public function scorecard(){

    return $this->hasMany('App\Scorecard');

}

public function score() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Score');
}
```

Scorecard model

```
public function course(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Course');

}

public function club(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Club');
}
```

In my controller I get the scores id from a dropdown in the request. I need to essentially get the following info:

1. the scores record which is easy as i have the score id.
2. use the scorecard_id from the scores table to get the scorecard record from the scorecards table
3. grab the course info from the courses table using the course_id thats in the scorecards table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eager load the relations using dot `.` as `scorecard.course` and it will load both scorecard and course.

```
$score = Score::with('scorecard.course')->find($id);
```

and then you can access corresponding attributes as:

```
$score->scorecard;
$score->scorecard->course;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

if `$id` is the scores id from a dropdown,

```
$score=Score::with('scorecard','scorecard.course')->where(['id'=$id])->first();
```

then,

```
print_r($score);
```

gives the scores record.

```
print_r($score->scorecard);
```

gives the scorecard record.

```
print_r($score->scorecard->course);
```

gives the courses record.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!